# Extend class from Pod library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

In my project I'm subclassing an existing class from a pod library because I don't want to change the pod source file directly so I can update the library in the future. The problem is that the method I'm overriding is making use of another method in a different class that has been declared as internal so it only can be called from classes within its own module.

Is there an easy solution for this? Can I add my new created class to the existing module?

Comment: Do you tried using `extension`? Or using inheritance?

Comment: Inheritance. I'm overriding an existing method-

Comment: Is calling `super.overridenMethod()` out of the question? If you are changing some part of the behaviour, maybe it can be done after default inplementation?

Comment: overridenMethod() contains code that breaks my app. That's why I want to reimplement it modifying that part.